# Angular custom control - star rating - value from input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

```
<div class="rating">
<div style="display: inline-block"
  *ngFor="let starred of stars; let i = index"
  (click)="rate(i + (starred ? (value > i + 1 ? 1 : 0) : 1))">
      <ng-container *ngIf="starred; else noStar"><mat-icon class="filled">star</mat-icon></ng-container>
      <ng-template #noStar><mat-icon class="empty">star_outline</mat-icon></ng-template>
    </div>
</div>   


 @Component({
  selector: 'jfg-star-rating',
  templateUrl: './star-rating.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./star-rating.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => StarRatingComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]

})
export class StarRatingComponent implements ControlValueAccessor{

  stars: boolean[] = Array(3).fill(true);

   // Allow the input to be disabled, and when it is make it somewhat transparent.
  @Input() disabled = false;
   @HostBinding('style.opacity')
   get opacity() {
     return this.disabled ? 1 : 1;
   }

   // Function to call when the rating changes.
   onChange = (rating: number) => {
   };

   // Function to call when the input is touched (when a star is clicked).
   onTouched = () => {
   };


   get value(): number {
     if(!this.disabled){
     return this.stars.reduce((total, starred) => {
       return total + (starred ? 1 : 0);
     }, 0);
     }
   }
   rate(rating: number) {
     if (!this.disabled) {
       this.writeValue(rating);
     }
   }

   // Allows Angular to update the model (rating).
   // Update the model and changes needed for the view here.
   writeValue(rating: number): void {
     if (!this.disabled) {
       this.stars = this.stars.map((_, i) => rating > i);
       this.onChange(this.value);
     }

   }

   // Allows Angular to register a function to call when the model (rating) changes.
   // Save the function as a property to call later here.
   registerOnChange(fn: (rating: number) => void): void {
     this.onChange = fn;
   }

   // Allows Angular to register a function to call when the input has been touched.
   // Save the function as a property to call later here.
   registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
     this.onTouched = fn;
   }

   // Allows Angular to disable the input.
   setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
     this.disabled = isDisabled;


   }
 }
```

Im trying to make a component for star rating. I made it to work properly as an input. So i can press on the stars to get the correct value as a formControl and pass it to my services. But my problem is that i have tried to make my component to get value as an @input and set number of stars based on that value. I have tried inputing the value and setting it everywhere i could but still had no effect. If you could suggest me how can i proceed to set value form the input i would be glad :)

Comment: The only input in that is the `disabled` property?

Comment: Beforeu, is a custom form control component. So, the logic is that work as any input, you can use < star-ratting [(ngModel)]="your_variable" /> or < star-ratting fromControlName="myControl" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have implemented `ControlValueAccessor` so you should be able to set the value by `ngModel` which is two binding. You don't need any other input to set the value. So you can use your `StarRatingComponent` as -

```
<jfg-star-rating [ngModel]="3"></jfg-star-rating>
```

OR

```
<jfg-star-rating [(ngModel)]="rating"></jfg-star-rating>
```

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-sample-vv4s6b